# Como agregar un ID a una tabla sql?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, tablas, datos, id

Edito, no aclare algo, necesito agregar por medio de una consulta, no puedo modificar la tabla, no cuento con los accesos.
quiero agregar un ID mediante una consulta, tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_historial](
[GESTI] [int] NOT NULL,
[CIOBL] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[TNRSO] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[MEVEN] [varchar](100) NULL ) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

como veran no hay un atributo para saber cuantos registros existen en la tabla, se que se puede poner un ID mediante consulta, pero no recuerdo

Comment: Quizá deberías de explicar un poco mejor lo que necesitas, ya que los `atributos` de una tabla no cuentan los registros. Si quieres contar cuantos registros tienes, puedes hacer un `Select count(*) from dbo.tb_historial`

Comment: @javi fer2 lo que necesito es que se agrege un ID, al inicio, sin modificar la tabla, el count no me sirve por que solo va contar el total de los registros, y necesito que esten enumerados por un ID

Comment: Puedes utilizar [row_number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

Comment: @javi fer2 Muchas gracias , el ejemplo de esa pagina esta muy completo

Comment: Gracias a ti también, por el comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select ROW_NUMBER()
    over (order by --aqui el criterio que quieras
        Gesti
    ) as rn
    From dbo.historial
```

Row_number numera las filas, empezando en 1, por el criterio de ordenación que se requiera. Puede ser una columna, o una expresión.