# Como seleccionar datos desde un determinado ID hasta los nuevos que se generen en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, tablas, id

vuelvo a preguntar para complementar la anterior pregunta que hice, sobre como hacer id automaticos.

[Pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/513900/como-agregar-un-id-a-una-tabla-sql?noredirect=1#comment913355_513900)

ahora mi duda es, tengo esta tabla con 1000 registros y sigue incrementadose cada dia, lo que quiero hacer obtener los registros desde el 500 hasta los ultimos id que se vayan agregando hoy y mas adelante.

la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo para agregar IDs

```
Select ROW_NUMBER()
over (order by --aqui el criterio que quieras
    Gesti
) as rn
From dbo.historial
```

Comment: Si no tienes una fecha de inserción o de alta en la tabla me temo que es imposible

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Rayos pense que si se podia solamente con el ID, bueno gracias

Comment: No, por que ese ID autogenerado y dinámico depende de un orden que nada tiene que ver con la fecha de inserción.

Answer (score 0):

La función [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) lo que hace es enumerar las filas.

Para obtener el resultado deseado, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Gesti) as rn
   From dbo.historial 
) t where t.rn >= 500
```